# Transiting through Brussels

Tags: transit, bru

I am travelling from India to Jamaica via Brussels and I will get a boarding pass to Brussels. My next connecting flight is Jetairfly. Do I get a new boarding pass from Jetairfly for travelling on? Do they transfer my luggage to their flight upon request?

Comment: What airline are you flying from India to Brussels?  Did you purchase this itinerary as a single ticket?

Answer (score 0):

Given your description and since Jetairfly do not service India, I'm assuming the first half of your flight is with an airline other than Jetairfly.  If that's the case you will have to collect your luggage in Brussels and check-in with Jetairfly at the airport.

Comment: That's not necessarily the case if Jetairfly interlines with the carrier flying from India.